# Struts forms still empty

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am beginner developer and i'm working on a web application in Java whith struts.
I have a problem with my struts form which stay empty after user enters informations. I've tried many way to resolve it but nothing worked. Maybe the code lines will help you to help me ;). 
My Jsp page :

```
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
    <div class="content" align="center">
        <form action="statistiques.do" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="module1">
            <tr>
                <td><font size="3">&Eacute;tat&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="choixEtat">
                        <option value='1' selected>Tous</option>
                        <option value='2' >Actif</option>
                        <option value='3' >Inactif</option>
                    </select>
                </td>   
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Date de d&eacute;but&nbsp;:<span style="font-weight: bolder; color: red;">&nbsp;&#42;</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dateDebut" size="10" maxlength="10" id="date" value="" 
                           required="required">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date de fin&nbsp;:<span style="font-weight: bolder; color: red;">&nbsp;&#42;</span></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="dateFin" size="10" maxlength="10" id="date2" value="" 
                           required="required">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><font size="3">Charg&eacute;(e)(s)</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="chargeMatricule">
                        <option value="0" selected></option>
                        <% for (Utilisateur u : utilisateurs) {%>
                        <option value="<%=u.getUtilisateurMatricule()%>"><%=u.getUtilisateurNom() + ", " + u.getUtilisateurPrenom()%></option>
                        <%}%>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><font size="3">Activit&eacute;&nbsp;:&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="activiteNom">
                        <option value="0" selected></option>
                        <% for (String s : activites) {%>
                        <option value="<%=s%>"><%=s%></option>
                        <%}%>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td colspan='5' align="center">
                <input type="submit">
            </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </div>
</td>
```

and my action :

```
public class ActionStatistiques extends DispatchAction {

public ActionForward module1(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    FormStatMod1 forms = (FormStatMod1) form;
    ServiceStatistiques service = new ServiceStatistiques();
    String dd = forms.getDateDebut();
    String dateDebut = dd.substring(6, 10) + '-' + dd.substring(3, 5) + '-' + dd.substring(0, 2);
    String df = forms.getDateFin();
    String dateFin = df.substring(6, 10) + '-' + df.substring(3, 5) + '-' + df.substring(0, 2);
    Collection[] collections = service.module1(forms.getChoixEtat(), dateDebut, dateFin);
    Collection<Flux> listef = collections[1];
    String activiteNom = forms.getActiviteNom();
    String chargeMatricule = forms.getChargeMatricule();
```

Hope, someone will see what's wrong.
Have a nice day!!

Comment: ???? You JSP includes no Struts tags, just plain HTML/JSP. Have you tried following a tutorial?

Comment: I don't need to add struts tag, my form contains : form action="statistiques.do". And i am using an Action form who is declared in the struts-config file!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found my way!!! Like many times it was a stupid omission ... a setter missed in my form!!! Never will forget to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<html:form>`

Here is the example - http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/faqs/actionForm.html

Comment: I have already tried this solution but it doesn't work... but thank you for the idea. Hope to find the good one quickly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the form is rendered using Struts tags but you can use JSP EL expressions to populate the input fields. For example

```
<input type="text" name="dateFin" size="10" maxlength="10" id="date2" value="${formStatMod1.dateFin}" required="required">
```

Comment: But i never used it and i never had problems with struts actionforms!! I tried it but sadly it doesn't work... I am very curious to find a solution to these problem because this is one of the last thing i miss to finish my application... Many thanks for your answer!!

Comment: You can post `struts-config.xml` at least to know what form beans are populated with the request.